# Android ,Calling buttons from include tag

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I followed @seanhodges sample of the footer bar (android navigation bar bottom) :
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369975?tab=votes#tab-top

Is it possible to call it from include tag and then access each button at runtime

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
     <include  android:id="@+id/footer" layout="@layout/footer" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

when calling it from the include tag, it looks good on the screen.
I try reach the buttons at run time but could get it work..

I know this is not the way but I am looking for something like this...

```
 Button _BackButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.footer);

_BackButton.setText("new text");

 Button _Backhome= (Button)findViewById(R.id.footer);

_Backhome.setText("new text");
```

can it be done through the -include- tag?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ids of the buttons from within the footer layout, using the example you linked to you can get the back button by doing this:

```
Button _BackButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
```

The View hierarchy will be sure to go through the included view when looking for a specified id.